# Duas rotas GET no mesmo arquivo .ts - Nodejs + MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, http

Eu preciso fazer duas rotas GET, uma para retornar todos os registros do bd e outra com um parâmetro caso o usuário pesquise um medicamento.
Quando tentei antes, se fosse a primeira requisição, funcionava, mas eu tive um problema com `connection.end()`, e depois que removi do código, tudo que é retornado é o primeiro GET (todos os medicamentos) mesmo passando o parâmetro.

**routes.js**

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'medicines',
});

routes.get('/meds', (request, response) => {
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM meds LIMIT 16`, (err: any, result: any) => {
        if (err) {
            response.write(JSON.stringify(err));
            response.end();
        } else {
            return response.send(result).status(200);
        }
    });

});

routes.get('/meds/:substancia', (request, response) => {
    const search = request.query.substancia;
    const sql = `SELECT * FROM meds WHERE substancia LIKE '%${search}%' LIMIT 16`;
    
    connection.query(sql, (err: any, result: any) => {
        console.log('query: ' + sql)
        if (err) {
            response.write(JSON.stringify(err));
            response.end();
        } else {
            return response.send(result).status(200);
        }
    });

});

export default routes;
```

**Insomnia**
[image: Print Insomnia]

Como fazer a rota/bd entender que é outro GET? O que estou fazendo de errado? É a primeira vez que uso Nodejs + MySQL.

Comment: Está usando `request.query.substancia` quando na verdade você precisa usar o `request.params.substancia`

Comment: Fiz a modificação mas ainda não ta funcionado :/ Alguma outra ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: Da forma em que foi criada a 2º rota para executa-la, a url tem que estar dessa forma ``http://localhost:3333/meds/trazodona``

Comment: Era isso! Muito obrigada ^^
Agora como faz pra ser uma url no formato ``localhost/meds/?substancia="xxxx"``?
Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda :)

Comment: De uma olhada aqui [Para entender melhor](https://pt.linkedin.com/pulse/entendendo-par%C3%A2metros-em-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-uma-vez-por-todas-henrique) como funciona as rotas

Comment: Se usar via query params só vai precisar de uma rota a rota do get ‘/meds’

Comment: Obrigada guys. Agora entendi e deu certo! Feliz Natal <3

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que na definição da rota está declarando um parâmetro via a URL, mas está utilizando um *query parameter*.

Para resolver o problema basta utilizar corretamente o atributo de parâmetro na URL.

Neste caso você deveria utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
routes.get('/meds/:substancia', (request, response) => {
    const search = request.params.substancia; // <-- mudança aqui
    const sql = `SELECT * FROM meds WHERE substancia LIKE '%${search}%' LIMIT 16`;
    
    connection.query(sql, (err: any, result: any) => {
        console.log('query: ' + sql)
        if (err) {
            response.write(JSON.stringify(err));
            response.end();
        } else {
            return response.send(result).status(200);
        }
    });
});
```

Repare que no trecho em destaque estamos utilizando o `request.params` ao invés de `request.query` (a maneira que você está utilizando).

Depois para fazer a chamada da api o texto em questão deve ser passado na url como um parâmetro, ex:

```
curl http://localhost:3333/meds/acetilsalicílico
```

Para este exemplo de chamada se colocarmos um `console.log` na variável `search` teremos a seguinte saída:

```
const search = request.params.substancia;
console.log(search)
//acetilsalicílico
```

Para mais informações consulte a documentação do [`objeto request do express`](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#req).